# Converting a formatted file to json with awk (dealing with non-empty lines)

Tags: json, awk, gawk

Here's a sample file that I want to convert to json.

```
Name: Jack
Address: Fancy road and some special characters :"'$@|,
   City
   Country
ID: 1
```

The special characters are double quote, single quote, $, @, pipe. I thought I can use the record separator in `awk`:

```
awk -F ":" '{RS="\n"}{print $1}'
```

However, what I get is:

```
Name:
Address
   City
   Country
ID
```

I experimented with changing the record separator to "^[a-zA-Z0-9]" to try and catch strings that don't start with a space, but somehow this doesn't work. Another attempt is to simply parse the file line by line and format the output conditional on each line's content, but this is slow.

Ideally, I would convert the file to:

```
{
"Name": "Jack",
"Address": "Fancy road and some special characters :\"'$@|, City, Country",
"ID": "1"
}
```

Comment: @hek2mgl: yes, sorry, correcting it now. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idk why your question talks about non-empty lines when there are no empty lines in your example but with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { printf "{" }

match($0,/^(\S[^:]+):\s*(.*)/,a) {
    prt()
    key = a[1]
    val = a[2]
    next
}

{ val = gensub(/,\s*$/,"",1,val) gensub(/^\s*/,", ",1) }

END { prt(); print "\n}" }

function prt() {
    if (key != "") {
        printf "%s\n\"%s\": \"%s\"", (++c>1?",":""), key, gensub(/"/,"\\\\&","g",val)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
{
"Name": "Jack",
"Address": "Fancy road and some special characters :\"'$@|, City, Country",
"ID": "1"
}
```

Some extra comments on the code:

`match()`

> The match function searches the string, string, for the longest, leftmost substring matched by the regular expression, regexp. It returns the character position, or index, of where that substring begins (1, if it starts at the beginning of string).

`\S`

> Matches any character that is not whitespace. Think of it as shorthand for ‘[^[:space:]]’.

`\s`

> Matches any whitespace character. Think of it as shorthand for ‘[[:space:]]’.

Comment: @hek2mgl: sorry, I think this is my bad.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed `/["\047$@|]/` to `/["]/` since it was my mistake to escape non-double quotes, and it works perfectly! :)

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need to put `"` in a bracket expression, it's just a literal character. I updated my answer to reflect your updated desired output.